# Converting a linux alias to a desktop launcher

Tags: .desktop, alias, cat

I would like to know how to convert the following  simple alias to a desktop launcher:

```
cat ~/info1.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `.desktop` file, say `read-info1.desktop` and add the following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Read info1
Comment=Read the info1.txt file in Terminal
Exec=gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'cat /home/YOUR-USERNAME/info1.txt; exec bash'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=text-x-generic
```

Of course put your actual username in place of `YOUR-USERNAME` in the `Exec=` line.